# Use of navigation manager over href in blazor web-assembly

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

In Blazor web-assembly, is there a reason why should I use NavigationManager over a plain a href link structure?

For example

```
<a href="/test">Test</a>

<a @onclick="@LinkToTest">Test</a> or
<button @onclick="@LinkToTest">Test</button>

@code
{
void LinkToTest()
{
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/test");
}
}
```

Is there a difference how the app would be rendered or routed?

Comment: The only difference I know of  is that you can force a reload with `NavigateTo`.  Not something you should do very often, but...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking inside the source code for `NavigationManager.NavigateTo`, it just invokes an internal javascript function using the JsInterop. Looking at the source on the javascript side, that basically just sets `location.href`. So I think it's safe to say that calling `NavigateTo` is equivalent to just using a plain href.

Comment: A little bit more to it than that, `href` will force a complete page reload while `NavigateTo` keeps the app context (variable etc) intact and doesn't reload the entire app.